# How to use Prime31 Google In App Billing Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, prime31

I just bought "Google In App Billing Plugin for unity3d" by Prime31. I don't understand how to use it in the game that I want to develop.

Can you please show me a code example? I understand I need to use my app key, but I don't know what to do next.
And how to a I make test purchases with this plugin?

Please help as much as you can, because I am really stuck on this subject for quite a while.

This is some of my "purchase maker" object called MoneyTakerScript (inherits from MonoBehaviour):

```
void Start()
{

    string key = "My App Key...";


    GoogleIAB.init(key);

    var skus = new string[] { "cl.48931", "tp.58932", "mmm.68393" };
    GoogleIAB.queryInventory( skus );

    TPS = GameObject.Find("TPBtn").GetComponent(typeof(TPScript)) as TPScript;
    CLS = GameObject.Find("CLBtn").GetComponent(typeof(CLScript)) as CLScript;
    MMM = GameObject.Find("MMBtn").GetComponent(typeof(MMMScript)) as MMMScript;
}


public void Purchase(string ProductId)
{
    GoogleIAB.purchaseProduct(ProductId);

}



public void UseProduct(string ProductId)
{


    if (ProductId.Contains("cl"))
    {
        CLS.MakeCL();

    }
    if (ProductId.Contains("tp"))
    {
        TPS.MakeTP();

    }
    if (ProductId.Contains("mmm"))
    {
        MMM.MakeMMM();

    }

    GoogleIAB.consumeProduct(ProductId);
}
```

And this is some of my "purchase listner" object code:

```
 void purchaseSucceededEvent(GooglePurchase purchase)
{
    //Debug.Log( "purchaseSucceededEvent: " + purchase );
    MoneyScript.UseProduct(purchase.productId);

}

  void Start()
{
    MoneyScript = GameObject.Find("MoneyTaker").GetComponent(typeof(MoneyTakerScript)) as 
    MoneyTakerScript;        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and solved it!

This line was missing in my AndroidManifest.Xml for some reason:

```
<activity android:name="com.prime31.GoogleIABProxyActivity"></activity>
```

Just added the line and now I have In App Purchase!!